# Running javascript from a bash script

Tags: javascript, bash

I am new to learning bash script programming and was wondering if anyone here knows how can I execute javascript that would normally be embedded into an html page?

So from a bash script, I would like to execute ( for example ):

`<script type="text/javascript" src="scriptName.js"></script>`

Thank you very much for anyone's help.

Comment: Node? http://nodejs.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283234/javascript-interpretor-in-bash, but the answers are largely 4 years old and several are no longer useful.

Answer (score 20):

You'll need a Javascript runtime like [Node.js](http://nodejs.org).

To evaluate a snippet of code:  `$ node -e "console.log('hello')"`

To run a script: `$ node script.js`

Answer (score 4):

How about using env like:

my-file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("hello from test file");
```

Make the file executable.

```
chmod +x my-file
```

Then run it:

```
node my-file
hello from test file
```

Comment: I did run the script directly without calling node at first like this: ./myfile.js